# Python matplotlib divide scatterplot into categories based on slope

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of x and a list of y values. I'd like to construct a scatterplot in Matplotlib and divide the dots into five categories based on their x and y coordinates, like in the image below:

[image]

```
angles = [0, 18, 36, 54, 72, 90]
colors = ['r','g','b','c']
x = [....]
y = [....]
```

All of the points in the divided category will be the same color. It would also be great to have a legend for the categories. I am new to Matplotlib and Python, does anyone know how I can approach this?

Comment: To get multiple colors on your scatter plot, you have to call `plt.scatter()` for each new color. Are your x-y values arranged in any particular order?

Comment: The values are not arranged in any particular order. I have experimented with plt.scatter(), but I'm not sure how to divide the points like depicted in the image.

Comment: Could you post the values of x and y?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid not, since it is a gigantic dataset. However, please check out BPL's answer and use his code to generate the random x and y values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example which will give you a little idea to get started:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

import math
import random

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

w, h = 7, 5
a = [[random.random() * w, random.random() * h] for i in range(100)]
plt.plot(*zip(*a), marker='o', color='r', ls='')

for deg in [18, 36, 54]:
    r = 10
    line = Line2D([0, r * math.cos(math.radians(deg))],
                  [0, r * math.sin(math.radians(deg))],
                  linewidth=1, linestyle="-", color="green")
    ax.add_line(line)

ax.set_xlim(0, w)
ax.set_ylim(0, h)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I compensate for the difference in scale between the x and y coordinates? My coordinates are mostly decimal values, while the y are large numbers. The angles wouldn't match in these cases.